# Characterization of a domain of holomorphy

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I need to show that the property of being a domain of holomorphy is the same as being a holomorphically convex domain (this result is known as Cartan-Thullen theorem). However, the proofs I found in textbooks (e.g. Shabat) look ugly and are hard to digest.

Is there a reference with a better proof? Can you share your intuition on looking at this result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at Hörmander's SCV book.

Comment: Try https://www.jirka.org/scv/

Comment: Thanks, Jiří! It’s an excellent text